# How does concurrency work while using async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, concurrency

I couldn't understand the execution order of the two codes below.

```
async function main(test)
{
  while(1) console.log(test);

}

main("a");
main("b");
```

This code above logs infinite "a".

```
async function main(test)
{
  while(1) await console.log(test);

}

main("a");
main("b");
```

While this code above logs infinite "a" and "b".

I wanted to understand async/await better but this behaviour above made me confused. Like how are those log functions handled by event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `async` function runs **synchronously** until the first `await`, `return`, or implicit return (the code falling off the end of the function). That's so it can start the asynchronous process that it will later report the completion of (by settling the promise it returns). So your first example logs `a` forever because that's done by the synchronous part of the first call to `main`; execution never reaches the second call to `main`.

Your second example introduces asynchronousness by adding `await` (it doesn't matter that what `await` is awaiting isn't a promise [`console.log` returns `undefined`]; it gets wrapped in one). That means that the first call to `main` runs synchronously until after the first `console.log`, then stops and returns a promise while it waits for the promise wrapped around `undefined` to settle.¹ That allows the second call to `main` to go forward, doing the same thing. At that point, the code making the calls to `main` is complete and any pending promise callbacks can be executed. The first pending promise callback is for the `await` in the first call to `main`, so that call does another loop iteration; the second pending promise is for the `await` in the second call to `main`, so it does another loop iteration; and so on, and so on, and so on.

You mentioned "concurrency." The two calls to `main` in your second example do run concurrently but are **not** multi-threaded; instead, they each alternately get access to the one main thread briefly until their next `await`. JavaScript works on a model of one thread per "realm" (loosely, per global environment). So you don't have to worry about threading issues like reordered operations or stale caches like you would in a multi-threaded environment (unless you're using [shared memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer), but you aren't in that code); there's only one thread.

---

¹ Technically, the promise is already settled in this case before `await` starts awaiting it (because it's just a promise wrapped around `undefined`), but when you attach to a promise, it never triggers your code synchronously, even if the promise is already settled.

Answer (score 0):

Using Asynchronous functions within Javascript usually resolves data that is not readily available. Examples include calling from a database and scraping web pages for data.

The code provided endlessly loops because there is no end to the said loop (`while`). In the context of the code provided, `while(1)` will always remain true, as there is no condition to state otherwise. In practical use, loops are designed to cease when a condition is met.

Here's a basic example of using a `while` loop sourced from [MDN Docs covering break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)

```
let n = 0;

while (n < 3) {
  n++;
}

console.log(n);
// expected output: 3
```

To better understand asynchronous programming within Javascript, [I highly recommend the MDN Docs on async functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

To answer your question regarding console logging's interactions with `await`: JS will 'freeze' the script when it reads an `await` and work on completing its defined actions, **then** returns to read the following line. In the context of the code, Javascript is doing its job. It circles back to a lack of a `break` or condition for the loop.